# Can't get pass the 'Allow Cookies' page with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So this is my code:

```
def login(self,username,password):
     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     self.driver.get("http://instagram.com")
     sleep(5)
     allow_button = '//button[text()="Allow Cookies"]'
     self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, allow_button).click()
     sleep(10)
```

Before I even get to the username and password page, I couldn't even click 'Allow all cookies' on the page.

I also tried the XPATH, by copying directly from chrome, but it still doesn't work:

```
def login(self,username,password):
     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     self.driver.get("http://instagram.com")
     sleep(5)
     allow_button = '//*[@id="mount_0_0_03"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[1]'
     self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, allow_button).click()
     sleep(10)
```

I was trying to login Instagram with Selenium.

Comment: Try using only 'Allow' instead of 'Allow Cookies' and using WebDriverWait with Expected condtion like this `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Allow')]"))).click()`.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.